# Send data from one data table to other

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to send data from sql to oracle using bulk copy.
Here is the code

```
            string sqldb = "server=DOR-SQLTEST\\DORSQLSERVER;" + "initial catalog=RD2KTEST;" + "user id=amehra;" + "password=Research@322";
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(sqldb);
            sqlconn.Open();


            string sqlstring="select TOP 10 POSITION_ID, POSITION_DESC  from T_CD_POSITION";

            SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, sqlconn);
            SqlDataReader reader = scmd.ExecuteReader();


            while(reader.Read())
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("entered to write to oracle.......\n\n");

                 string oradb = "Data Source=UHAMPTST;user id=ocg_de;password=rd2k";
                OracleConnection oraconn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
                oraconn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("orca conn established....");


                using( OracleBulkCopy orca_bulk_copy = new OracleBulkCopy(oraconn))
                 {
                    orca_bulk_copy.DestinationTableName = "t_test_postion";

                    orca_bulk_copy.WriteToServer(reader);//line 38

                    orca_bulk_copy.Close();
                    orca_bulk_copy.Dispose();
                 }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

I'm getting error at line 38 as Oracle Exception occurred.
Kindly rectify the problem

Comment: @DanBracuk the one with comments orca_bulk_copy.WriteToServer(reader);//line 38

Comment: Its really urgent, kindly reply